# mouseleave triggered at the intersection of blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseleave

need to sidebar was functional, but when you move the cursor to the left of `<div id="out_trigger"></div>` worked Event alert('cursor out...').

Now the event is triggered when you hover over an element el_1,el_2. This should not be.

https://jsfiddle.net/vkymqd6h/

solution has been found: https://jsfiddle.net/ahpfx551/

Comment: You should not judge Russians by their English, but by their capacity of drinking vodka!

Comment: Sorry for my English )

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
#out_trigger{
  background: red;



   width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 2000;

}
#left_sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4000;
    top: 160px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    /* pointer-events: none; */
}

.item
{
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 35px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.item:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}

#sidebar_trigger{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vjv19z2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your CSS. Here is [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamkarthik08/vkymqd6h/1/) deleting the CSS. Which is working fine

```
#out_trigger{
 background: red;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px; 
}
```

Comment: Ya instead of using Position : fixed in your css. Use other way of positioning. My guess is Position: fixed which causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code from mouseleave to mouseout

```
$("#out_trigger").mouseout(function(){
  alert('cursor out from #out_trigger');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the positioning and the hierarchy of elements.
However, if you do stick to keeping the same structure, you have to bypass the `left_sidebar` div.

The following code works:

```
$("#out_trigger").mouseout(onMouseOut);

function onMouseOut(event) {
  //the original element the event handler was assigned to
  var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;

  while (e && e.parentNode && e.parentNode != window) {
    if (e.parentNode == this ||  e == this) {
      if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    e = e.parentNode;
  }

  // mouse event handled here
  alert('cursor out from #out_trigger');
}
```

Comment: thank you, but the hierarchy did not matter. Everything was much simpler.
By the way your solution does not work when you hover the cursor over el_1 and move it to the right.

Comment: Yes ideally `left_sidebar` should be inside `out_trigger` in the hierarchy level. Will edit answer to support this.